# How to query Bookshelf/Knex for PostgreSQL large objects

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

We are using Bookshelf.js/Knex.js with PostgreSQL 9.4 on different projects. Works like a charm. Bookshelf.js/Knex.js a pleasure to work with.

Lately we have added PostgreSQL large objects to our schema and databases and are looking for the best way to retrieve them in this context.

So far, we are successfully retrieving the large objects using the [pg-large-object](https://github.com/Joris-van-der-Wel/node-pg-large-object) module (error handling removed for legibility):

```js
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'postgres',
  connection: {
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'postgres',
    password : '1234',
    database : 'someapp',
    charset  : 'utf8'
  }
});
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

var pg = require('pg'); 
var LargeObjectManager = require('pg-large-object').LargeObjectManager;
var conString = 'postgres://postgres:1234@localhost/someapp';

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {

    var man = new LargeObjectManager(client);

    client.query('BEGIN', function(err, result) {
        var oid = 123;
        var bufferSize = 16384;
        man.openAndReadableStream(oid, bufferSize, function(err, size, stream) {
            stream.on('end', function() {
                client.query('COMMIT');
                done();
            });

            var fileStream = require('fs').createWriteStream('bigfile.data');
            stream.pipe(fileStream);
        });
    });
});
```

As you can read, that's not DRY because we don't reuse the Bookshelf.js/Knex.js existing connection.

So the question is: what is the best way to accomplish this?

- Trying to retrieve and reuse the `pg` connection client used in the Knex postgres dialect? But how? It seems we can at best get a hand on `knex.client.connectionSettings`
- Directly using the PostgreSQL functions for handling large objects from Knex as seems suggested in the comment ["You work with large objects using simple functions."](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/321#issuecomment-39033421)? But how to do that concretely? Anyone a Knex raw query for that?

Comment: Have you tried to use `bytea` type instead of `LO` ?

Comment: Yes, using `bytea` works well with Bookshelf.js/Knex.js. But using large objects is now a requirement (for reasons out of scope here). So we don't want to use `bytea` instead of large objects. Thanks for your suggestion!